# Get previous 12months with month end date from given month using Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I had an use-case to fetch last 12months with end-date of that month from given date.

For Example if I give input as ('2021-04-23'), the output should be:

**output1 = ('2021-04-30', '2021-03-31', '2021-02-28', '2021-01-31', '2020-12-31', '2020-11-30', '2020-10-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-08-31', '2020-07-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-04-30')**

**output2=('2021-04-01','2021-03-01','2021-02-01','2021-01-01','2020-12-01','2020-11-01','2020-10-01','2020-09-01', '2020-08-01','2020-07-01','2020-06-01','2020-05-01','2020-04-01')**

I had the code snippet

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val monthDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM")
val start = YearMonth.parse("2021-04", monthDate
val lastTwelveMonths=(0 to 12).map(x => start.minusMonths(x).format(monthDate)).toList
```

which returns last 12months from current month, Can any one please provide solution which includes end date too for previous 12 months. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.time.LocalDate`'s `withDayOfMonth()` for what you need:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
val inputDate = LocalDate.parse("2021-04-23")

(0 to 12).map{ n =>
  inputDate.minusMonths(n).withDayOfMonth(1).format(dateFormat)
}
// Vector(2021-04-01, 2021-03-01, 2021-02-01, 2021-01-01, 2020-12-01, 2020-11-01, 2020-10-01, 2020-09-01, 2020-08-01, 2020-07-01, 2020-06-01, 2020-05-01, 2020-04-01)

(0 to 12).map{ n => 
  val prevDate = inputDate.minusMonths(n)
  prevDate.withDayOfMonth(prevDate.lengthOfMonth).format(dateFormat)
}
// Vector(2021-04-30, 2021-03-31, 2021-02-28, 2021-01-31, 2020-12-31, 2020-11-30, 2020-10-31, 2020-09-30, 2020-08-31, 2020-07-31, 2020-06-30, 2020-05-31, 2020-04-30)
```